# Accept the "Play App Signing Terms" without uploading a certificate first

Tags: google-play-console, android-app-signing, android-app-bundle

I am migrating a few apps to App Signing, and to Android App Bundle. But since I'm not an account owner or account admin I can't do it.

In order to do it, you need to:

1. Upload the signing key (and optionally the upload key)
2. Accept the terms

The problem is that I am the developer, an admin only of my specific app. The terms have to be accepted by the **account owner/admin**. The account owner does not have the signing key, and shouldn't. So not sure how to proceed, as neither of us has all prerequisites for completing the process.

Q: Can the account owner somehow just accept the "Play App Signing Terms of Service", without having to upload a key?

---

P.S. There's the option to ask the account owner to make me **account admin**, which allows me to accept these specific terms (I'm currently only **app admin**). However, the account owner is not comfortable with giving me such high privileges, as they also have other apps on the same account. Not a solution.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this?

Comment: No, to be honest I decided to postpone this project, and use the old signing wherever I faced an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

1. Ask Owner to go to Google Play Console, from left menu select `Setup` > `App integrity`
2. Click on `Create release` button

[image: step 2]

3. Then click on `change app signing key`

[image: step 3]

4. Choose `use Google-generated key`

[image]

5. Accept license agreement
6. And voila, now you can use it without admin privileges.

[image: result]

Note: This is tested many times before.

Comment: Jabbar, it seems your example is of a new app. My situation involves already existing apps that were published as APK long time ago. The "App Integrity" page does not let me "Create release", as you suggest. The only options are to "Export and upload a key" in 3 different ways.